# "ORA-01017: invalid username/password" while connecting to an instance remotely as sysdba

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to connect to a remote instance as `sysdba` - however, I encounter the error: `"ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"`.

```
$ sqlplus "sys/xxxx@<IP>:1521/sid1 as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Sep 29 04:07:34 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

When I try to connect to another instance on the same server, I can get through:

```
$ sqlplus "sys/xxxx@<IP>:1521/sid2 as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Sep 29 04:07:23 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Can someone point me to what I may have missed here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems simply a password issue. Different instances may have different passwords, the SYS password is not necessarily the same for all the instances on the same server. Make sure `remote_login_passwordfile` is configured properly in the instances, and the password file exists for instance `SID1` on the server in `ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwSID1` (Linux-Unix) or `ORACLE_HOME/database/pwdSID1.ora` (Windows).

If you do not know the correct SYS password, you can recreate the password file, for example:

`orapwd file=$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwsid1 password=xxxx force=y`

Answer (score 2):

> From [Oracle ORA-01017 tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01017.htm) by Donald Burleson:
>
> #### Checklist for ORA-01017 errors:
>
> The core issue with an ORA-01017 error is an invalid user ID and passwords combination, but other than an incorrect password, there are user ID issues that may contribute to the ORA-01017 error:
>
> - It may be that the user ID is invalid for the target system - The user ID exists as the *username* column in the *dba_users* view.
>
>   ```
>   select username from dba_users;
>   ```
> - Check your `$ORACLE_SID` environmental parameter.  If your `$ORACLE_SID` is set to the wrong system ID then you may get a ORA-01017 error because you are connecting to the wrong database.
> - If using [external OS user authentication](http://www.dba-oracle.com/security/local_os_authentication.htm) (*ops$* or [remote_os_authent](http://www.rampant-books.com/aud_123.htm)) you need to verify that the user ID is valid.  You can tell if you are using external authentication because you connect without providing a user/password combination, and only provide a forward slash to the connect string, (e.g. *connect / as sysdba;*).
> - Check your *tnsnames.ora* to ensure that the TNS service name points to the correct server and instance name.  If you specify an incorrect *tnsnames.ora* service name, then the user ID and password may not exist in that database.

You can find extra information in the SAP on Oracle discussion [ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1263676)

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded from Oracle 11g to 18C on a system using certain OS user. The next day I was trying to access that system through my own username(different from one with which I upgraded).
Then, I got this error. I even used ORADIM to delete the existing sid and create a new one.
However, after some time I realized that I had logged in using my own user.
Then, I switched and the problem was gone!

Comment: How can your mistake be answer to this question? Why shouldn't one downvote this answer?