# ORA-01017 when connecting remotely as sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Good morning,

While installing a database for Oracle Entreprise Manager Cloud Control (OEMCC) I can't login as sysdba, neither localy using `sqlplus SYS@MYSID as sysdba` nor remotely using the OEMCC installer :

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ sqlplus SYS@MYSID as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 29 10:14:28 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I did some research :

Here : [“ORA-01017: invalid username/password” while connecting to an instance remotely as sysdba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116445/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-while-connecting-to-an-instance-remotely)
On oracle support : [Troubleshooting ORA-1031 or ORA-1017 Errors When Connecting As SYSDBA (Doc ID 730067.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=361118066611399&id=730067.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=516d54xmz_4)

It seems to be a different case :

- Localy I can connect using the system user (not as sysdba) : `sqlplus system@MYSID` then enter password, it works. So tnsnames.ora is correct. (Either localy and remotely)
- The password file is correctly created, using : `${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/orapwd file=${ORACLE_HOME}/dbs/orapwmysid password="*********" force=y` (just to be sure I connected using `sqlplus / as sysdba` then did `alter user sys identified by "*********" account unlock;`)
- The parameter `remote_login_passwordfile` is set to `EXCLUSIVE` :

```
    SQL> show parameter remote_login_passwordfile;

    NAME                       TYPE    VALUE
    -------------------------  ------  --------- 
    remote_login_passwordfile  string  EXCLUSIVE
```

- The orapw file rights are correct :

```
    [oracle@myserver ~]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwmysid 
    -rw-r-----. 1 oracle dba 6144 May 29 10:14 /opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwmysid
```

- Remote login using system works :

```
[oracle@anotherserver ~]$ sqlplus system@MYSID

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 29 13:18:52 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Tue May 28 2019 15:41:20 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Do you have an idea, something I could investigate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filenames (and Oracle instance names) on Linux are case sensitive. You keep using `MYSID` but you created the password file as `orapwmysid`. `MYSID` as a TNS alias is not case sensitive. `MYSID` as an instance name is case sensitive and having the password file named lowercase will prevent logging in using SYS with the above error.

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ps -ef | grep smon
oracle     923 31725  0 16:56 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto smon
oracle   31761     1  0 May15 ?        00:00:37 ora_smon_MIN18
oracle   32529     1  0 16:49 ?        00:00:00 ora_smon_MIN19
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwMIN19
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 2048 Apr 30 00:17 /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwMIN19
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus sys/Oracle123@min19 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed May 29 16:56:37 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
[oracle@o71 ~]$ mv /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwMIN19 /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwmin19
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus sys/Oracle123@min19 as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed May 29 16:56:45 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:
```

Even if you change the SYS password with `ALTER USER...`, the password file will not be generated correctly in this case:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed May 29 16:58:19 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter user sys identified by Oracle123;

User altered.

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ls -l /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapw*
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 2048 Apr 30 00:17 /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwmin19
[oracle@o71 ~]$
```

Comment: You just saved my day, thank you very much Balazs :)